# Am I the only one having issues opening the zip file for sass sleuth?

Tags: sass, inspector

http://www.mobify.com/blog/sass-sleuth-debugging-sass-in-webkit-browsers/

I get the following error when I try to open this file, but not zip files from other websites...

```
Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.
```

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason WinRar doesn't like the way security settings are set up on my computer.  When I use 7zip it works just fine.  I uninstalled WinRar, but for those of you who prefer it try re-running the installer as admin and make sure you have admin access to the machine.  Some anti-virus programs will also block rights to certain programs if you aren't careful in setting specific application security policies.